# java: Button is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am new in java and i don't knonw how to solve this problem.Following is the code.The error shown is

```
java: Button is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

I have searched in mant websites and youtube and still i didn't get the correct solution for this problem.

```
public class Button implements ActionListener {
    JTextField jt1, jt2, jt3;
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

    Button() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JLabel jl1 = new JLabel("1st no:");
        jl1.setBounds(40, 40, 30, 30);

        JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("2nd no:");
        jl2.setBounds(40, 90, 30, 30);

        JLabel jl3 = new JLabel("Result:");
        jl3.setBounds(40, 150, 30, 30);

        jt1 = new JTextField();
        jt1.setBounds(90, 40, 100, 30);

        jt2 = new JTextField();
        jt2.setBounds(90, 90, 100, 30);

        jt3 = new JTextField();
        jt3.setBounds(90, 150, 100, 30);
        jt3.setEditable(false);

        b1 = new JButton("+");
        b1.setBounds(40, 200, 30, 30);
        b2 = new JButton("-");
        b2.setBounds(80, 200, 30, 30);
        b3 = new JButton("*");
        b3.setBounds(120, 200, 30, 30);
        b4 = new JButton("/");
        b4.setBounds(160, 200, 30, 30);
        b5 = new JButton("%");
        b5.setBounds(200, 200, 30, 30);
        jf.setLayout(null);
        jf.add(jl1);
        jf.add(jl2);
        jf.add(jt1);
        jf.add(jl3);
        jf.add(jt2);
        jf.add(jt3);
        jf.add(b1);
        jf.add(b2);
        jf.add(b3);
        jf.add(b5);
        jf.add(b4);
        jf.setSize(300, 400);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
        b5.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void ActionListener(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = jt1.getText();
        String b = jt2.getText();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(a);
        int m = Integer.parseInt(b);
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            int x = n + m;
            String r = String.valueOf(x);
            jt3.setText(r);
        } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
            int x = n - m;
            String r = String.valueOf(x);
            jt3.setText(r);

        } else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
            int x = n / m;
            String r = String.valueOf(x);
            jt3.setText(r);

        } else if (e.getSource() == b4) {
            int x = n * m;
            String r = String.valueOf(x);
            jt3.setText(r);

        } else if (e.getSource() == b5) {
            int x = n % m;
            String r = String.valueOf(x);
            jt3.setText(r);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Button();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call you class button. There is an AWT component with that name so it is confusing. Don't use a null layout and don't use setBounds. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

There is much to improve in the code, but what concerns the error
`Button is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener`,
it means that you should implement the actionPerformed method. So change `public void ActionListener(ActionEvent e)` to `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`, and the error will disappear:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String a = jt1.getText();
    String b = jt2.getText();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are implementing an interface to any your classes you need to override all of your interface methods inside your class which is not abstract.

As your Button class is implementing ActionListener interface you need to override its methods inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
}
```

Try to put this in your public class and outside any constructor. I hope this can help your code to get fix.